# When to use a <b-container>?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

According to the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout/#containers-b-container), using a `<b-container>` is key for the layout system:

> Containers (`<b-container>`) are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and is **required when using the grid system**.

I do not really understand where they should be used, though.

- as a way to encompass the overall page?
- as a container for `<b-row>`?
- as a container for any element?

What I am trying to find out is when I should use `<b-container>` in addition to an element. I am fairly sure that I should not (or do not have to) use it to pack a button for instance. But maybe when there are two buttons next to each other? (this is just an example - I am interested in the general case)

**Is there a clear rule for when to use `<b-container>`?**

Comment: You really only need to use the container when you want to use the grid layout system.  The rows and cols all depend on a parent container otherwise they do not layout properly.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question.. yes, it's way to encompass to whole page... no you do not *have* to use it... *unless* you're using the grid system in which case it would be used to contain the `<b-row>`

Answer (score 2):

The interesting aspect of this question is coming up on screens that are larger than the standard breakpoints of bootstrap in layouts that shall show the content-width limited but the background in the whole browser-width. Certainly this applies also to backgrounds with parallax-effect.
Common containers in Bootstrap limit the size to a defined width and therefore are not suitable for full-width backgrounds, they need an outer container where the desired full-width background can be applied. The only Bootstrap container type that has always 100% width has the class "container-fluid". For a quick overview of the container-definitions I add them in the following screenshot:

[image]

Even wrapping a bootstrap container in an outer container might not need a bootstrap class, it could be used like this, this first example could also be used for a background in zebra style:

```
<div class="container-fluid my-background-1">
    <!-- Limit the width for the content-cols: -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid my-background-2">
    <!-- Limit the width for the content-cols: -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It might be desired to have backgrounds that are images, like for parallax-effects, then the containers include no content but only background:

```
<div class="container-fluid my-background-1">
    <!-- Full width background -->
</div>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Limit the width for the content-cols: -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
        <div class="row"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below I add an image in larger width, but with a limited area of 1200px width to show the problem (concerning the drawn grid I never considered padding of the container-class, so it might not be 100% accurate):

[image]

So the important questions for the designer boil down to:

- what for a container shall be used (for content grid or exclusively for background)?
- shall the content-grid be limited to the common bootstrap breakpoints (max 1200 px) or shall even the content-grid exceed any thinkable width and just fill the available area in the browser?
- what kind of background shall be applied (images or zebra-style) and shall it be applied to the current container?
- if zebra-style background is used, shall it be applied only to the container width or will the whole width of the browser-window?
- shall images (like for parallax effects) only be added as backgrounds or better be referenced directly to enable easier accessible features like alt- and title-attributes (above I just assumed images as backgrounds always, so you have to rethink my words perhaps to replace that option by the two alternatives)?

I'm happy to edit my question if anything is still unclear, just leave further questions / unclear details as comment to let me know.

**Edit 1:**
For microlayouts like for buttons you better use the [flex-utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/) for being able to define clear and distinct wrapping behavior.